# xUnit tests not found when running in docker container

Tags: docker, .net-core, containers, xunit

I am making a Dockerfile for a dotnet core project with some xUnit tests. I want to run the unit tests when the images are being built. However when I docker build I get the following message at the test step:

> No test is available in /ciad/tests/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/Tests.dll. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build

WORKDIR /ciad

# restore
COPY API/API.csproj ./api/
RUN dotnet restore api/API.csproj
COPY Tests/Tests.csproj ./tests/
RUN dotnet restore tests/Tests.csproj

# copy src
COPY . .

# test
RUN dotnet test tests/Tests.csproj
```

I'm aware that this is an incomplete dockerfile. I'm just stuck with the tests at the moment. Could anyone see what I'm missing?

Good to mention that tests run fine in VS and "dotnet test" command works too. I can also see that the Tests projects' files are copied to the container. 
I run:

```
docker build -t testing .
```

Comment: The error talks about `/ciad/tests/`. Where do the test sources live? Are they under `/ciad/tests/` or `/ciad/Tests/`? Is that a *t* or *T*. Capitalization matters on Linux.

Comment: The project name is Tests.csproj.
Since the line "RUN dotnet restore tests/Tests.csproj" works, then I'm sure that the problem is not capital T.

Comment: Basically I wonder if anyone has any idea about "test discoverer & executors are registered" part in the error message?

Comment: `RUN dotnet restore tests/Tests.csproj` only works because you copied over the csproj into `tests/`, not `Tests`. And `restore` only uses the project file, not code. The code never existed at `tests/` and was never compiled and couldn't be found/executed by `dotnet test`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but why does it work when I change everything to small t, if you check my answer to the question? It's the same approach, isn't it?

Comment: That's a good question. I hate to admit it, but I don't know. I dont really know how docker modifies paths when tranferring files from Windows to Linux (container). From how I understand things, this should be the correct dockerfile: https://gist.github.com/omajid/29d4fb07b25d0705bf0e0d2a2687f755.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what was wrong but eventually thanks to tips from omajid I changed the tests project's name and folder to tests with small t and all other capital T in Dockerfile to small t and it worked! 
I hope this might help someone.

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build

WORKDIR /ciad

# restore
COPY API/API.csproj ./api/
RUN dotnet restore api/API.csproj
COPY tests/tests.csproj ./tests/
RUN dotnet restore tests/tests.csproj

# copy src
COPY . .

# test
RUN dotnet test tests/Tests.csproj
```